# Yii framework: how to get id from DB, when choosing related record from DB

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii-extensions, yii2-basic-app

I have text edit box with `Autocomplete::widget` on the web page.
Autocomplete populates from DB. When I start to type and choose Autocomplete item (which is the First Name from DB, in my case) I need to get the associated id from DB. How could this get implemented?

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use app\models\Rating;
use app\models\Teacher;
use yii\jui\AutoComplete;
use yii\web\JsExpression;



/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\Rating */
/* @var $form ActiveForm */

    $data = Teacher::find()
    ->select(['lname as value', 'lname as  label','id as id'])
    ->asArray()
    ->all();

    //print_r($data[0].id);//exit;


?>

<div class="rating-input">
ФИО
    <?php 

    echo AutoComplete::widget([
    'name' => 'Teacher',
    'id' =>'ddd',
    'clientOptions' => [
    'source' => $data,
    'autoFill'=>true,
    'minLength'=>'1',
     ],
     ]);
```

https://paste.ee/p/BtQav

Comment: You should include the code directly here. People might be reluctant to follow external links. Plus you save them some time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
  <input type="hidden" name="teacher_id" id="teacher_id" value="">

     <?php 

    echo AutoComplete::widget([
    'name' => 'Teacher',
    'id' =>'ddd',
    'clientOptions' => [
    'source' => $data,
    'autoFill'=>true,
    'minLength'=>'1',
    'select' => new \yii\web\JsExpression("function( event, ui ) {    
                    // $('#teacher_id').val(ui.item.id);//#teacher_id is the id of hiddenInput.
                     console.log(ui.item.id);
                 }")
     ],
     ]);
```

You have more information in documentation page : http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/830/simple-jui-autocomplete-in-yii2/